# How to design a car-packages-database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a logic-thinking problem.
How should I design following database?

A manufacturer sells cars. He sells them as they are, or with a package A, or with a package B, or with both packages.

I would create a table with the different car models, then a table with the different packages, but I don't know how to create the mapping-table, which links the cars to the different packages and prices?

The problem is the packages don't have a price (just the cars and the cars with packages included).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "offer" table. This table will contain price. 
Each offer should have at least one car and no, one, two, many, or all (if there will be more then 2 of them) packages.

[image]

Comment: How would I add this as an order line item when using foreign keys?

Comment: You are buying "offer". So You will put offer_id to order line. When You buy "offer", this "offer" contains always a car, and this "offer" may contain zero, one, two or more packages...    Anyway it MUST be listed as one line in order, because package doesn't have its own price... If You want to change order, You have to delete/add "offer" from/to order.

Comment: i don't get it right. i'm only able to connect one car with **one** package in the "package_to_offer" table, but how am i able to connect more than one packages to an "offer-car"? and isn't the "offer" table redundant, because it only represents the "car" table?

Comment: Offer ALWAYS contains a car (How sell packages (warranty?,airbags?) without car?). You can add zero, one, two, many packages to offer. Package_to_offer is M:N relation so You can add many package to one offer. Table offer isn't redundant because: packages can not be directly connected to car. Also if someone will add offer "to basket" only one relation will be needed: In order there will be only offer id.

Comment: Offer inherite from car (car's name). And has also it's specific parameter: price which depends on CAR, and sometimes(always?) on package/packages. Offer also agregate packages specified for this car and price.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that a car would have a manufacturers suggested retail price (MSRP).  Each package or option would have its own additional price on top of the MSRP.

I'd have a base Car table, a Package table, and another purchased Car table, one to many with a Customer table, where the Customer can associate their base Car with one or more Package instances.

Comment: Problem is that the packages don't have price tags.

Comment: Why not?  They should.  If they don't, you ought to know what the price of the base model with the package is.  Gotta have one somewhere, unless you're giving them away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it correctly, you need to use Table Inheritance.

You sell abstract products. One type of product is a car. Another is a "combo" (aka "marketing package") which is composed of other products.

There are some good data modeling books that cover this.